# Button OnClick="btnSave_Click" does not work in MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I am new to MVC architecture and I am struggling to get the Button onclick. Please help me trace the issue. I have a Telerik TreeView control, which is populated. Some of the nodes have child nodes and some of them doesn't.

Please let me know what changes need to be made to fix the issue
Here I am struggling to get it working.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/PostLogin.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<applications>>" %>

<%@ Import Namespace="ApplicationGrps" %>

<%@ Register assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" tagprefix="telerik" %>


<script runat="server" type="text/javascript">

    protected void Page_Load()
    {

        ApplicationGrps.Visible = true;
        ApplicationGrps.DataSource = ODS1;

        ApplicationGrps.DataFieldID = "ApplicationName";
        ApplicationGrps.DataFieldParentID = "ParentID";

        ApplicationGrps.DataBind();
        BindCheckedTags(ApplicationGrps);
    }

    protected void BindCheckedTags(RadTreeView treeView)
        {
          // Displays the checked nodes
        }


        protected void ODS2_Selecting(object sender, ObjectDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
        {
            e.InputParameters["ClientID"] = ViewData["ClientID"];
        }

    protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
               //Iterate through the tree and get all the nodes that are checked and submit it.
        }
</script>


<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    <link href="<%: Url.Content("~/Content/script-libraries/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.css") %>"
        rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>

</asp:Content>


<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <form id="form1" runat="server" method="post">

     <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <div>

       <telerik:RadTreeView id="AppModulesTreeView" runat="server" CheckBoxes="True" Visible="true" >


</telerik:RadTreeView>

<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ODS1" runat="server" 
    SelectMethod="GetAllApplicationModules"
    TypeName="ELS.BOS.Services.EntitlementProxy.EntitlementServiceClient">
</asp:ObjectDataSource>

<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ODS2" runat="server" 
    SelectMethod="GetApplicationModMappedByClientID" 
    TypeName="ELS.BOS.Services.EntitlementProxy.EntitlementServiceClient" 
          onselecting="ODS2_Selecting">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="ClientID" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
      <%--  <telerik:RadButton runat="server" onclick="btnSave_Click" 
            Text="Save">
        </telerik:RadButton>
        <telerik:RadButton ID="btnCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" 
            >
        </telerik:RadButton>--%>


        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="btnSave_Click" />

    </div>
    </form>


</asp:Content>
```

Please let me know if I need to use javascript or jquery to get this working. Please show me some samples on how to fire btnSave_click on button control click.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="btnSave_Click" />`, `asp:ObjectDataSource`, `ScriptManager`, ... in an ASP.NET MVC application?

**No.**

In an ASP.NET MVC applications you don't use server side controls (no `runat="server"`). You don't PostBack. There is no ViewState. There is no code behind. There are no events. There are no script managers. There are no object data sources. All this is specific to WebForms and is no longer used in MVC.

In an ASP.NET MVC application you have a Controller, a Model and a View. The view contains standard HTML markup which could be generated with the aid of HTML helpers. To call the controller you could use a normal link:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("link text", "actionName", "controllerName") %>
```

The controller contains actions which manipulate the model and choose the view to be rendered by passing it all the information it needs to show.

I would strongly recommend you start reading the tutorials here: http://asp.net/mvc about how MVC works and familiarize yourself with the very basics of this framework.